# base_url() method is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url()?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

is not working

I have loaded url helper too.
`$this->load->helper('url');`

and it properly showing the path after `<?php echo base_url();?`

```
path = http://[::1]/project/
```

and my complete path to  css file is 
http://localhost:8090/project/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

when I'm use an explicit link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8090/project/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

that is working.

What to do now?

Comment: load helper in autoload file .. May it resolve your issue

Comment: Could it be something as simple as needing a / before 'assets' in your link?

Comment: And/or your base_url isn't showing the port that is in your explicit link. Do you need to add the port?

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8090/project/';
```

in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'`.

Comment: If this (base_url) is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and path to installation.

Comment: @chhameed And he would get what he has already got. From [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L14) "WARNING: You MUST set this value!". I don't see one reason why avoid this reference.

Comment: I want to set it for server too.

Answer (score 0):

First load URL helper in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Edit `application/config/config.php` and set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8090/project/';
```

as `base_url()` reads its value from the config array

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps and it will sort-out the problem,

**1. View**

use this in your view,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); >assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**2. Config.php**

Go to *application/config/config.php* file, and set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8090/project/';
```

Don't forget the last "/". If you forget you have to manually add it in the view.

**3. autoload.php**

Go to *application/config/autoload.php* file, and set

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

This will work. Try it and let me know.